# PHP stdClass object, access with Constants

Tags: php, stdclass

The response is received in JSON, **$requestBody** holds the json response. The type of that class is stdclass.

Now, if I access it using

```
   $myCar=$requestBody->Car;
```

The value in $myCar is "Alpha". So, far so good.

I have defined a constants like, defined in "MyConstants.php"

```
   define("ITEM1","Car");
```

So, I am trying to access values from $requestBody using Constant. But I get nil. the code is listed below in "index.php"

```
<?php 

include 'MyConstants.php';

//Works 
$key=constant("ITEM1");
$carStr=$requestBody->key;

//Does not work 
$carStr2=$requestBody->constant("ITEM1");
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$requestBody->{ITEM1}
```

You might also consider to decode the json to an array:

```
$requestBody = json_decode($json, true);
$requestBody[ITEM1];
```

Comment: Thanks, could you provide some explanation on {ITEM1}